# Filter a list of class with element which starts with specific letters

Tags: c#, wpf, string, linq

I have a list of a class object, I need to filter that list with element which starts with these letters "GHB" and then set a listview control dataconext to it to display the elements

```
if(myList.ToList().FindIndex(x=> x.Name !=null)!=-1 )
{
  listview1.DataContext = myList.ToList().where(x=> x.Name.StarstWith("GHB"))
}
```

But it gives me an error when an element is null

Comment: a) that code won't compile because of casing issues. b) when you have an error, tell us about it. What is it? Where did it happen?

Comment: `myList.ToList().FindIndex(x=> x.Name !=null)!=-1` could be more readably expressed as `myList.Any(x => x.Name != null)`.

Comment: Did you consider checking if `x.Name` is null before calling a method on it?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm trying to do that with the if condition

Comment: @DainaHodges Your if condition checks if there are ANY items in myList that have a non-null name. So if you have ten items and one has a non-null name, you go ahead and checks all the names, including the null ones. I'm suggesting that *before* you *call the method* on the `Name` of a particular item, check if the `Name` property you are about to call the method on is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
listview1.DataContext = myList
    .Where(x => x != null 
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) 
        && x.Name.StarstWith("GHB"))
    .ToList();
```

...and remove the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

It gives you the error because your if condition is actually useless. You check whether `Name` in at least one element is not null, if so you try to access the variable. This of course will fail, because you need only 1 element with a valid name and the rest still can have `null` values which will lead to the `NullReferenceException`

What you can do is: check in the where clause additionaly whether `Name` is not null and if so only then check whether it `StartsWith("GHB")`:

```
listview1.DataContext = myList.Where(x => x?.Name != null && x.Name.StartsWith("GHB")).ToList();
```

this way you can save yourself the if condition.

I guess what you where trying to check is **if `Name` in all elements is not null**. In this case you can use the [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
if (myList.All(x=>x.Name != null)
```

EDIT: using the `?` will avoid that `Name` is checked if an element in the List is entirely `null`:

```
myList.Where(x => x?.Name != null && x.Name.StartsWith("GHB")).ToList();
```

Comment: @mm8 why exactly? the `&&` in the where condition should make sure that the second part is not evaluated if the first is `false`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @MongZhu: Sorry, it will raise an exception if myList contains a null reference. But you should still use the string.IsNullOrEmpty to validate the string :)

Comment: @mm8 I edited my post to incorporate the null check. `IsNullOrEmpty` is not really andantages here. But it would save you 1 further comparison, that is true